# How to identify specific child record and validate values

Tags: jmeter

When I'm calling get method I am getting multiple child records like below, I need to search whether my required entry is available or not?

I need to search three values, **description, service Code, Duration** combination from a specific record.

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": "C0000020-HC011EW",
        "description": "Anaesthesia For Surgery",
        "siteId": "HC011EW",
        "episodeTypeId": "I",
        "episodeType": "Inpatient",
        "serviceCode": "C0000020",
        "serviceCodeDescription": "Anaesthesia For Surgery",
        "duration": 360,
        "backgroundColour": "#ffd4e5",
        "status": "A",
        "includeInNewICESessions": false,
        "isSystemDefined": false,
        "industryStandardCodeScheme": "ISC"
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000011-HC011EW",
        "description": "Consultation with Minor Treatment",
        "siteId": "HC011EW",
        "episodeTypeId": "O",
        "episodeType": "Outpatient",
        "serviceCode": "C0000011",
        "serviceCodeDescription": "Consultation with Minor Treatment",
        "duration": 60,
        "backgroundColour": "#ffffba",
        "status": "A",
        "includeInNewICESessions": false,
        "isSystemDefined": false,
        "industryStandardCodeScheme": "ISC"
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate presence of a specific record you can use [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) configured like below:

[image]

Text representation of the [JSONPath query](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-path-extractor-jmeter) just in case:

```
data[?(@.description =='Anaesthesia For Surgery' && @.serviceCode =='C0000020' && @.duration == 360)]
```

The assertion will fail the sampler(s) in its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) if the element matching the JSON Path query will not be present in the response.

Comment: Thanks Ivan for quick response, When I did negative testing and duration as 60 which is valid value but from different child record and still executed successfully. @Ivan G

Comment: Thanks Madhu for "valuable" comment but you're lying at my face. When I did negative testing and duration as 60 using the [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-dummy-sampler) and the same assertion I've provided it worked just as it should be working. Here is the evidence: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Xed.gif. So my expectation is that you edited the wrong entry.

Comment: Why would I lie to a person who is trying to help me? I have tried and failed that is why I have added the comment. let me try again.